# Set an attribute of a property element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a image that I want to have a larger preview using a tooltip.

```
<Image MaxWidth="585" Margin="2" Source="{Binding Preview, IsAsync=true}">
    <Image.ToolTip MaxWidth="800"> <!-- Error: Attribute "MaxWidth" is not allowed in property element -->
        <Image Source="{Binding Preview, IsAsync=true}" />
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

How do I change the `MaxWidth` property of the `ToolTip`? Second question: How can I use the parent `Source` value within the child binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the [ToolTip property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip) is of type `object`, so it does not have a `MaxWidth` property. Because the `ToolTip` can accept an arbitrary `object`, to set the `MaxWidth` you should put a [ToolTip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip) (or another WPF element) inside of the `ToolTip` property and set the `MaxWidth` on that.

Something like:

```
<Image MaxWidth="585" Margin="2" Source="{Binding Preview, IsAsync=true}">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip MaxWidth="1000" MaxHeight="600">
            <Image Source="{Binding Preview, IsAsync=true}" />
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```